# Exiting a Do While Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this sub as part of a larger piece of code. Effectively what I am trying to do is go down column C, copy where there is a value until I hit "End" and paste in "L1". If there is no value in the cell I don't want the loop to end as there will be gaps. When I try to run the code, it gets stuck in the loop without exiting.

```
Sub LoopEmailAdd()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While Cells(1, "C").Value = "Email"
    If Cells(1 + i, "C").Value <> Empty And Cells(1 + i, "C").Value <> "End" Then
        Cells(1 + i, "C").Copy _
        Destination:=Range("L1")
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Cells(1 + i, "C").Value = "End" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace **Empty** with **""** and try again.

Comment: Learn to debug. Watch the value of i after each loop.

Comment: @D_Bester the issue isnt that I dont know how to debug... the issue is I cant get out of the loop. Nothing happens to the value of the cell because the first part of the code does what I want it to. Where I am failing is figuring out something to triger the loop to stop (in my case the "End")

Comment: `Empty` doesn't mean what you think it does. You check for `Empty` using the `IsEmpty` function, and that returns `True` when the cell's value is a `Variant` that has *no value* - not even an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you describe, you can loose the loop and use `Find` instead, try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopEmailAdd()

Dim FindRng As Range

Set FindRng = Columns(3).Find("End")

' make sure Find was successful finding "End"
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    Cells(FindRng.Row - 1, "C").Copy Range("L1")
Else ' in case Find failed
    MsgBox "Unable to find End in column C", vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```